# como agregar el evento del enter al hacer onchange en un combobox

Tags: jqgrid

tengo un combobox en el campo "ship_via", el combobox aparece cuando clic en la celda y luego cuando hago enter el combobox desaparece quedando la opcion seleccionada, creo que esto de hacer enter es del mismo jqgrid, lo que deseo hacer es que  al seleccionar el item del combobox(evento onchange) se quede la opcion seleccionada en la celda , es decir lo mismo que al hacer enter, pero en el evento onchange, gracias por su ayuda

```js
  var mydata = [
           { id: "1",  name: "test1", note: "note1", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true, ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00" },
           { id: "2",  name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
           { id: "3",  name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "430.00" },
           { id: "4", name: "test4", note: "note4", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true, ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00" },
           { id: "5",  name: "test5", note: "note5", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
           { id: "6",  name: "test6", note: "note6", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "430.00" },
           { id: "7",  name: "test7", note: "note7", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true, ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00" },
           { id: "8",  name: "test8", note: "note8", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
           { id: "9",  name: "test9", note: "note9", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "TN", total: "430.00" },
           { id: "10",  name: "test10", note: "note10", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: true, ship_via: "TN", total: "530.00" },
           { id: "11", name: "test11", note: "note11", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "530.00" },
           { id: "12",  name: "test12", note: "note12", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "530.00" }
    ],
       $grid = $("#grid1"),
       initDateEdit = function (elem) {
           $(elem).datepicker({
               dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
               autoSize: true,
               changeYear: true,
               changeMonth: true,
               showButtonPanel: true,
               showWeek: true
           });
       },
       initDateSearch = function (elem) {
           setTimeout(function () {
               $(elem).datepicker({
                   dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
                   autoSize: true,
                   changeYear: true,
                   changeMonth: true,
                   showWeek: true,
                   showButtonPanel: true
               });
           }, 100);
       },
       numberTemplate = {
           formatter: 'number', align: 'right', sorttype: 'number',
           editrules: { number: true, required: true },
           searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'le', 'gt', 'ge', 'nu', 'nn', 'in', 'ni'] }
       },
       editingRowId,
       myEditParam = {
           keys: true,
           oneditfunc: function (id) {
               editingRowId = id;
           },
           afterrestorefunc: function (id) {
               editingRowId = undefined;
           }
       };
    $grid.jqGrid({
        data: mydata,
        datatype: "local",
        colNames: ['Client',  'Amount', 'Tax', 'Total', 'Closed', 'Shipped via', 'Notes'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'name', index: 'name', align: 'center', editable: true, width: 65, editrules: { required: true } },
    
            { name: 'amount', index: 'amount', width: 75, editable: true, template: numberTemplate },
            { name: 'tax', index: 'tax', width: 52, editable: true, template: numberTemplate },
            { name: 'total', index: 'total', width: 60, template: numberTemplate },
            {
                name: 'closed', index: 'closed', width: 70, align: 'center', editable: true, formatter: 'checkbox',
                edittype: 'checkbox', editoptions: { value: 'Yes:No', defaultValue: 'Yes' },
                stype: 'select', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne'], value: ':Any;true:Yes;false:No' }
            },
            {
                name: 'ship_via', index: 'ship_via', width: 105, align: 'center', editable: true, formatter: 'select',
                edittype: 'select', editoptions: {
                    value: 'FE:FedEx;TN:TNT;IN:Intim',
                   /* dataInit: function (elem) {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            $(elem).multiselect({
                                minWidth: 100, 
                                height: "auto",
                                selectedList: 2,
                                checkAllText: "all",
                                uncheckAllText: "no",
                                noneSelectedText: "Any",
                                open: function () {
                                    var $menu = $(".ui-multiselect-menu:visible");
                                    $menu.width("auto");
                                    return;
                                }
                            });
                        }, 50);
                    },*/
                    multiple: false,
                    defaultValue: 'IN'
                },
              stype: 'select', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne'], value: ':Any;FE:FedEx;TN:TNT;IN:IN' }
            },
            { name: 'note', index: 'note', width: 60, sortable: false, editable: true, edittype: 'textarea' }
        ],
        pager: '#pager',
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
        sortname: 'id',
        sortorder: 'asc',
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
        height: "100%",
        editurl: 'clientArray',
        onSelectRow: function (id) {
            if (editingRowId) {
                $(this).jqGrid('restoreRow', editingRowId, myEditParam);
            }
            $(this).jqGrid('editRow', id, myEditParam);
        },
        caption: "Demonstrate the usage of jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget"
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<link href="http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/themes/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

 <table id="grid1"></table>
```

Comment: Pero el combo en la celda se va a desplegar cuando pongas en edicion la celda sino simplemente mostrara el valor. Sino pones foco en la celda no se desplegara el combo

Comment: Hola, leandro gracias por tu ayuda ahora eh puesto al combobox al editar. He cambiado mi pregunta, gracias

Answer (score 1):

No sé si es la mejor manera, pero aquí dejo un método para hacerlo en dos simples pasos:

1. Añade un controlador para los eventos de la lista desplegable. Para ello puedes usar [`dataEvents`](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules).
2. En el controlador del evento `change`:

   1. Encuentra el ID de la file
   2. Lanza el evento de guardado de datos

El código sería algo así:

```
    // AM - Aqui defines los controladores de eventos para la lista desplegable
    dataEvents: [
      // AM - el controlador para el evento onchange
      {  
        type: 'change',
        fn: function(e) {
          // AM - Obtén el id de la fila en la que se encuentra la lista desplegable
          var rowId = $(e.target).closest('tr').attr('id');
          // AM - Guarda los valores de la fila
          $grid.saveRow(rowId);
        }
      }
    ]
```

Y aquí una demo de cómo quedaría el código (los cambios van comentados con `// AM -` para que sean fáciles de encontrar):

```js
var mydata = [
  { id: "1",  name: "test1", note: "note1", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true, ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00" },
  { id: "2",  name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
  { id: "3",  name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "430.00" },
  { id: "4", name: "test4", note: "note4", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true, ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00" },
  { id: "5",  name: "test5", note: "note5", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
  { id: "6",  name: "test6", note: "note6", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "430.00" },
  { id: "7",  name: "test7", note: "note7", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true, ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00" },
  { id: "8",  name: "test8", note: "note8", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
  { id: "9",  name: "test9", note: "note9", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "TN", total: "430.00" },
  { id: "10",  name: "test10", note: "note10", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: true, ship_via: "TN", total: "530.00" },
  { id: "11", name: "test11", note: "note11", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "530.00" },
  { id: "12",  name: "test12", note: "note12", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "530.00" }
],
    $grid = $("#grid1"),
    initDateEdit = function (elem) {
      $(elem).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
        autoSize: true,
        changeYear: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        showWeek: true
      });
    },
    initDateSearch = function (elem) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        $(elem).datepicker({
          dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
          autoSize: true,
          changeYear: true,
          changeMonth: true,
          showWeek: true,
          showButtonPanel: true
        });
      }, 100);
    },
    numberTemplate = {
      formatter: 'number', align: 'right', sorttype: 'number',
      editrules: { number: true, required: true },
      searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'le', 'gt', 'ge', 'nu', 'nn', 'in', 'ni'] }
    },
    editingRowId,
    myEditParam = {
      keys: true,
      oneditfunc: function (id) {
        editingRowId = id;
      },
      afterrestorefunc: function (id) {
        editingRowId = undefined;
      }
    };
$grid.jqGrid({
  data: mydata,
  datatype: "local",
  colNames: ['Client',  'Amount', 'Tax', 'Total', 'Closed', 'Shipped via', 'Notes'],
  colModel: [
    { name: 'name', index: 'name', align: 'center', editable: true, width: 65, editrules: { required: true } },

    { name: 'amount', index: 'amount', width: 75, editable: true, template: numberTemplate },
    { name: 'tax', index: 'tax', width: 52, editable: true, template: numberTemplate },
    { name: 'total', index: 'total', width: 60, template: numberTemplate },
    {
      name: 'closed', index: 'closed', width: 70, align: 'center', editable: true, formatter: 'checkbox',
      edittype: 'checkbox', editoptions: { value: 'Yes:No', defaultValue: 'Yes' },
      stype: 'select', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne'], value: ':Any;true:Yes;false:No' }
    },
    {
      name: 'ship_via', index: 'ship_via', width: 105, align: 'center', editable: true, formatter: 'select',
      edittype: 'select', 
      editoptions: {
        value: 'FE:FedEx;TN:TNT;IN:Intim',
        multiple: false,
        defaultValue: 'IN',
        // AM - Aqui defines los controladores de eventos para la lista desplegable
        dataEvents: [
          // AM - el controlador para el evento onchange
          {  
            type: 'change',
            fn: function(e) {
              // AM - Obtén el id de la fila en la que se encuentra la lista desplegable
              var rowId = $(e.target).closest('tr').attr('id');
              // AM - Guarda los valores de la fila
              $grid.saveRow(rowId);
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      stype: 'select', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne'], value: ':Any;FE:FedEx;TN:TNT;IN:IN' }
    },
    { name: 'note', index: 'note', width: 60, sortable: false, editable: true, edittype: 'textarea' }
  ],
  pager: '#pager',
  rowNum: 10,
  rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
  sortname: 'id',
  sortorder: 'asc',
  viewrecords: true,
  gridview: true,
  height: "100%",
  editurl: 'clientArray',
  onSelectRow: function (id) {
    if (editingRowId) {
      $(this).jqGrid('restoreRow', editingRowId, myEditParam);
    }
    $(this).jqGrid('editRow', id, myEditParam);
  },
  caption: "Demonstrate the usage of jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<link href="http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/themes/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

 <table id="grid1"></table>
```